# Print a file's last modified date in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, file, date, unix

I can't seem to find how to print out the date of a file. I'm so far able to print out all the files in a directory, but I need to print out the dates with it.

I know I need to attach a date format with the echo of the entry, but all I can't find the correct format.

```
echo "Please type in the directory you want all the files to be listed"

read directory 

for entry in "$directory"/*
do
  echo "$entry"
done
```

Comment: read -p "Please type in the directory you want all the files to be listed" directory

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can use the
[`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)
command

```sh
stat -c %y "$entry"
```

More info

```
%y   time of last modification, human-readable
```

Comment: `for entry in "$directory"/*
do
  stat -c%y "$entry"
done`

Doesn't work. Prints out stat: missing operand in terminal

Comment: Hm, could it be my unbuntu? Do you know what the requirements of using `stat` is?

Comment: Note that on OS X (Mac), it's `stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" filename` (see `man stat` **examples** for more details)

Comment: Note that on BSD the `stat` command has a different syntax. My case for FreeBSD: `stat -f %Sm -t %F" "%R filename`.

Answer (score 352):

Isn't the 'date' command much simpler?  No need for awk, stat, etc.

```
date -r <filename>
```

Also, consider looking at the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) for date formatting; for example with common date and time format:

```
date -r <filename> "+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: Much simpler then using stat / more available.

Comment: It looks like BSD (or at least OS X's) `date`'s doesn't have this. Its `-r` is just used to provide a timestamp to format. You'll have to use GNU date to get this functionality.

Comment: On OSX use: date `stat -f "%Sm" -t "%m%d%H%M%y" "${1}"`

Comment: @Mich - I get `stat no such file or directory`

Comment: On OS X 10.10 date -r <filename> works as advertised, although the man page doesn't  describe any <filename> argument.

Comment: is there a way to get more granular time than seconds?

Comment: yes @AlexanderMills you can just specify your format `date -r <filename> "+%b %d %Y %T %Z"`

Comment: No `date -r` on OS X 10.11, but `gdate -r` from GNU Core Utils works.

Comment: In macOS 10.13 `date [-r seconds | filename]` is fully documented in the `man` page, and works as expected.

Comment: I love this answer, particularly because `date -r $FILE +%s.%N` can provide more precision than `stat -c%Y`

Comment: **Piped**: `echo "${file}" | xargs date +%s -r`

Comment: How'd this change for directory?

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively, you may try also :

```
date -r filename +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20807343/6320039

Comment: @UlysseBN no it's slightly different.  He's advocating for a better date format.

Answer (score 16):

On OS X, I like my date to be in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` in the output for the file.

So to specify a file I would use:

```
stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" [filename]
```

If I want to run it on a range of files, I can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in /var/log/*.out; do
  stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$i"
done
```

This example will print out the last time I ran the `sudo periodic daily weekly monthly` command as it references the log files.

---

To add the filenames under each date, I would run the following instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in /var/log/*.out; do
  stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$i"
  echo "$i"
done
```

The output would was the following:

```
2016-40-01 16:40
/var/log/daily.out
2016-40-01 16:40
/var/log/monthly.out
2016-40-01 16:40
/var/log/weekly.out
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to prevent the line break and keep the file name appended to the end of the date without adding more lines to the script.

---

*PS - I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as I'm a Python user by day, and have different versions of `bash` installed on my system instead of `#!/bin/bash`*

Comment: In case you haven't figured out the line break part, the -e flag is available for the echo program. Example usage could be:  `echo -e "$(stat -f %Sm -t %Y%m%d_%H%M%S $AFile)\t$AFile."`. In your case it could be:  `echo -e "$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$i")\t$i."`

`

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @StevePenny answer, you might want to cut the not-so-human-readable part:

```
stat -c%y Localizable.strings | cut -d'.' -f1
```

Answer (score 4):

For the line breaks i edited your code to get something with no line breaks.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /Users/anthonykiggundu/Sites/rku-it/*; do
   t=$(stat -f "%Sm"  -t "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$i")
   echo $t : "${i##*/}"  # t only contains date last modified, then only filename 'grokked'- else $i alone is abs. path           
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If file name has no spaces:

```
ls -l <dir> | awk '{print $6, " ", $7, " ", $8, " ", $9 }'
```

This prints as the following format:

```
 Dec   21   20:03   a1.out
 Dec   21   20:04   a.cpp
```

If file names have space (you can use the following command for file names with no spaces too, just it looks complicated/ugly than the former):

```
 ls -l <dir> | awk '{printf ("%s %s %s ",  $6,  $7, $8); for (i=9;   i<=NF; i++){ printf ("%s ", $i)}; printf ("\n")}'
```

Comment: Ah, I see! That mostly works, except for the files with the spaces in the names. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Actually, I tried it again, and it doesn't work... turns out I was trying out a directory that had file names without spaces. =/ Edited my answer below

Comment: when you say it does not work, can you say what is the error? it works for me when i executed it on my system.

Comment: I got a "no such file or directory".

Comment: That is because you passed a value of `<dir>` which does not exist....the code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: turns out that I had forgotten the quotes needed for `$entry` in order to print correctly and not give the "no such file or directory" error. Thank you all so much for helping me!

Here is my final code:

```
    echo "Please type in the directory you want all the files to be listed with last modified dates" #bash can't find file creation dates

read directory

for entry in "$directory"/*

do
modDate=$(stat -c %y "$entry") #%y = last modified. Qoutes are needed otherwise spaces in file name with give error of "no such file"
modDate=${modDate%% *} #%% takes off everything off the string after the date to make it look pretty
echo $entry:$modDate
```

Prints out like this:

```
/home/joanne/Dropbox/cheat sheet.docx:2012-03-14
/home/joanne/Dropbox/Comp:2013-05-05
/home/joanne/Dropbox/Comp 150 java.zip:2013-02-11
/home/joanne/Dropbox/Comp 151 Java 2.zip:2013-02-11
/home/joanne/Dropbox/Comp 162 Assembly Language.zip:2013-02-11
/home/joanne/Dropbox/Comp 262 Comp Architecture.zip:2012-12-12
/home/joanne/Dropbox/Comp 345 Image Processing.zip:2013-02-11
/home/joanne/Dropbox/Comp 362 Operating Systems:2013-05-05
/home/joanne/Dropbox/Comp 447 Societal Issues.zip:2013-02-11
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to get a file's modification date in `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` format. Here is how I did it:

```
date -d @$( stat -c %Y myfile.css ) +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

*Explanation.* It's the combination of these commands:

```
stat -c %Y myfile.css # Get the modification date as a timestamp
date -d @1503989421 +%Y%m%d%H%M%S # Convert the date (from timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the modification date of a file in the format YYYYMMDD_hhmm:

```
date -r <file> "+%Y%m%d_%H%M"

    20240119_1018

MODDATE=`date -r <file> "+%Y%m%d_%H%M"`

echo $MODDATE

    20240119_1018
```

This can also be done in a brute force way with

```
stat -c %y <file>

    2024-01-19 10:18:17.000000000 -0500

stat -c %y <file> | sed "s/^\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\) \(..\):\(..\).*$/\1\2\3_\4\5/"

    20240119_1018

MODATE=`stat -c %y <file> | sed "s/^\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\) \(..\):\(..\).*$/\1\2\3_\4\5/"`

echo $MODATE

    20240119_1018
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
ls -lrt filename |awk '{printf "%02d",$7}'
```

This will display the date (a current day of a month) in 2 digits.

If between **1** to **9** it adds "0" prefix to it and converts to 01 - 09.

Hope this meets the expectation.

Comment: It's an anti-pattern to parse `ls` output.