# C preprocessor __TIMESTAMP__ in ISO 8601:2004

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor, icc

How can I have a `__TIMESTAMP__` replacement in ISO 8601:2004?

`__TIMESTAMP__`

```
Sat Jul  6 02:50:06 2013
```

vs

`__TIMESTAMP_ISO__`

```
2013-07-06T00:50:06Z
```

Comment: Can't understand why the guys in GCC team haven't implemented that yet. ISO 8601 is been there for a pretty long time now... https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Oh ye optimist!  You wouldn't really expect one standard to pay attention to another, would you?  The `__TIMESTAMP__` define is not in standard C, just so as you are aware.  It would be great to have a format like your proposed `__TIMESTAMP_ISO__` (would you always want Zulu time, or would it be better to have the local time zone offset?), but frankly, the easiest way to get it added might be a patch to GCC and Clang and so on.

You can try monkeying with `asctime()` as suggested by [user1034749](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034749/user1034749)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17498672/15168), but I'd rather not try that.

In the GCC 4.8.1 [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), there's an interesting warning suppression:

> `-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined`
>   Do not warn if certain built-in macros are redefined. This suppresses warnings for redefinition of `__TIMESTAMP__`, `__TIME__`, `__DATE__`, `__FILE__`, and
>   `__BASE_FILE__`.

This suggests you could try:

```
gcc ... -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__TIMESTAMP__=$(date +'"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"') ...
```

(Note the hieroglyphics necessary to get the string from `date` surrounded by double quotes.)  However, some earlier versions of GCC do not support the option; I don't recall seeing it before.  You can still redefine `__TIMESTAMP__`:

```
$ gcc -std=c99   -Wall -Wextra  -O xx.c -o xx
$ ./xx 
Fri Jul  5 19:56:25 2013
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -D__TIMESTAMP__=$(date +'"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"') -O xx.c -o xx  
<command-line>: warning: "__TIMESTAMP__" redefined
$ ./xx
2013-07-05T20:10:28
$
```

Not very pretty, but it works...  Oh, and just for the record, the source code was (trivial):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __TIMESTAMP__);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using this in my makefile: `CFLAGS += -D__TIMESTAMP_ISO__=$(shell date -u +'"\"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ\""')` works like a charm with clang, gcc, icc, etc. :)

Comment: Glad it works — it should.  Theoretically, you should not be using a name that starts with double-underscore; they're reserved for 'the implementation'.  As I noted, it is unlikely you'll actually run into problems, but you could equally as well use `-DTIMESTAMP_ISO=...` and be completely clear of risk (of colliding with future incarnations of 'the implementation').

Comment: :) I will update my usage as you recommend! Also, if I use `-r $(SRC)` where `SRC` is a make variable for the currently compiled file as in `CFLAGS += -DTIMESTAMP_ISO=$(shell date -r $(SRC) -u +'"\"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ\""')`, I match the original `__TIMESTAMP__` behaviour precisely; namely the date does not change on each build unless the source file has been modified prior to a build.

Comment: Very nice explanation, hence the +1. However, please note that this hack is _nonportable_, works only on Unix variants. It relies on the `date` command and a `bash` shell.

Comment: @user465139: the non-C code assumes a POSIX environment with the POSIX [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) command and a POSIX-compliant shell that recognizes `$(…)` for command substitution.  The quoting relies on POSIX shell too.  For a Windows environment, I'd probably write a C program to generate `#define TIMESTAMP_ISO "2014-09-28T12:00:03"` in a file such as `timestamp.h` and then `#include "timestamp.h"` in the code being compiled.  This would also work on POSIX-ish systems, of course.

Comment: @CetinSert .. but fails with ccache inside docker cached directory :)

Answer (score 4):

@Jonathan Leffler's answer provides an excellent solution but there might be one thing was ignored:
The original question was asking alternative format of `__TIMESTAMP__` while `__TIMESTAMP__` is to be expanded to string of last **modified** date-time of current source file.
However, the original answer was in fact assigning `__TIMESTAMP__` with date-time of gcc being run (i.e. **building** time), which is working as `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.

**How to improve**:
With @mmond's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391208/print-a-files-last-modified-date-in-bash), replaces the `date +'"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"'` command in `-D__TIMESTAMP__=...` with `date +'"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"' -r xx.c`, i.e. to add option `-r xx.c` to reference *xx.c* when running `date` command. The *xx.c* is the source code being built.

**Reference:**
According to GCC's `[manual][2]`

> `__TIMESTAMP__`
>   This macro expands to a string constant that describes the date and time of the last modification of the current source file.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to define a string constant that holds the date part of the compile time stamp. It wouldn't be difficult to add the time part to it, and to make it work from `__TIMESTAMP__` instead of `__DATE__`.

```
constexpr unsigned int compileYear = (__DATE__[7] - '0') * 1000 + (__DATE__[8] - '0') * 100 + (__DATE__[9] - '0') * 10 + (__DATE__[10] - '0');
constexpr unsigned int compileMonth = (__DATE__[0] == 'J') ? ((__DATE__[1] == 'a') ? 1 : ((__DATE__[2] == 'n') ? 6 : 7))    // Jan, Jun or Jul
                                : (__DATE__[0] == 'F') ? 2                                                              // Feb
                                : (__DATE__[0] == 'M') ? ((__DATE__[2] == 'r') ? 3 : 5)                                 // Mar or May
                                : (__DATE__[0] == 'A') ? ((__DATE__[2] == 'p') ? 4 : 8)                                 // Apr or Aug
                                : (__DATE__[0] == 'S') ? 9                                                              // Sep
                                : (__DATE__[0] == 'O') ? 10                                                             // Oct
                                : (__DATE__[0] == 'N') ? 11                                                             // Nov
                                : (__DATE__[0] == 'D') ? 12                                                             // Dec
                                : 0;
constexpr unsigned int compileDay = (__DATE__[4] == ' ') ? (__DATE__[5] - '0') : (__DATE__[4] - '0') * 10 + (__DATE__[5] - '0');

constexpr char IsoDate[] =
{   compileYear/1000 + '0', (compileYear % 1000)/100 + '0', (compileYear % 100)/10 + '0', compileYear % 10 + '0',
    '-',  compileMonth/10 + '0', compileMonth%10 + '0',
    '-',  compileDay/10 + '0', compileDay%10 + '0',
    0
};

// Test that it gets it right today
#include <cstring>
static_assert(strcmp(IsoDate, "2020-11-06") == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a really cross-platform way to have compile time stamp string formatted in ISO 8601 or any other format defined at compile-time, you can instead consider using [CMake](http://cmake.org) (which is always good to consider using).

What you want [can be easily accomplished with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31401540/1990577).

Comment: "easily accomplished". LOL. I really would like to use and understand CMake. It just looks like I'd need to invest 6 months in order to save 2 days, then.

Answer (score -1):

clang and gcc used C function "asctime" for this purpose, I suppose icc also uses it. On Linux you can use LD_PRELOAD to catch asctime call and replace with any string that you want.