# Different format of __DATE__ macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

C has a predefined macro `__DATE__`, that shows the date of the compiled source file .
The date is displayed in the format **"Mmm dd yyyy"** .

Is there any way to be formatted this date, using macros ?
In this format **"yyyy Mmm dd"**.

Instead of being :

> Jul 19 2013

Should be :

> 2013 Jul 19

Comment: I don't think there is a way. you have to do it pragmatically.

Comment: @chris C11 standard; `6.10.8.1 Mandatory macros
1 The following macro names shall be deﬁned by the implementation:
_ _DATE_ _ The date of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character
string literal of the form "Mmm dd yyyy", where the names of the
months are the same as those generated by the asctime function, and the
ﬁrst character of dd is a space character if the value is less than 10. If the
date of translation is not available, an implementation-deﬁned valid date
shall be supplied`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, You've got to be kidding me. I searched for `__DATE__` without the spaces. Removed previous wrong bloat.

Comment: @MarkGarcia 16.8.1 [cpp.predefined]

Comment: You might want to consider the technique given in response to the question [C preprocessor `__TIMESTAMP__` in ISO 8601:2004 format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498556/c-preprocessor-timestamp-in-iso-86012004/17499323#17499323)?  Or then again, you might not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C you could have a macro that generates a compound literal on the fly that has the order that you like, something like

```
#define FDATE (char const[]){ __DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], ..., ' ', ... , '\0' }
```

in all places where it matters your optimizer should be able to handle this efficiently.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in C++ because ISO C++ forbids compound literals.

Comment: @Rapptz, C++ should have possibilities to create similar temp objects on the fly. Whether you could achieve something that would be optimized as this one in C, I wouldn't be sure.

Comment: C++11 uses initializer lists, which are almost the same. E.g. `auto date {  __DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], ... `

Comment: @Rapptz: even for C++03, say `(std::string() + __DATE__[7] + __DATE__[8] + `...`)`

Comment: The later seems to be missing the `const` qualification, though, and the possibility to allocate that statically, which the C construct allows.

Comment: @MSalters You wouldn't be able to use it in a macro though like the OP wants.

Comment: @Rapptz: The initializer list can be in a macro, no problem.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone is looking for a way to convert `Mmm DD YYYY` into a string `YYMMDD`  with ASCII digits only (like `"220103"`), then here's the code for that. It should work in C and C++ both:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char version[6+1] =
{
   // YY year
   __DATE__[9], __DATE__[10],

   // First month letter, Oct Nov Dec = '1' otherwise '0'
   (__DATE__[0] == 'O' || __DATE__[0] == 'N' || __DATE__[0] == 'D') ? '1' : '0',
   
   // Second month letter
   (__DATE__[0] == 'J') ? ( (__DATE__[1] == 'a') ? '1' :       // Jan, Jun or Jul
                            ((__DATE__[2] == 'n') ? '6' : '7') ) :
   (__DATE__[0] == 'F') ? '2' :                                // Feb 
   (__DATE__[0] == 'M') ? (__DATE__[2] == 'r') ? '3' : '5' :   // Mar or May
   (__DATE__[0] == 'A') ? (__DATE__[1] == 'p') ? '4' : '8' :   // Apr or Aug
   (__DATE__[0] == 'S') ? '9' :                                // Sep
   (__DATE__[0] == 'O') ? '0' :                                // Oct
   (__DATE__[0] == 'N') ? '1' :                                // Nov
   (__DATE__[0] == 'D') ? '2' :                                // Dec
   0,

   // First day letter, replace space with digit
   __DATE__[4]==' ' ? '0' : __DATE__[4],

   // Second day letter
   __DATE__[5],

  '\0'
};

int main(void)
{
  puts(__DATE__);
  puts(version);
}
```

Output:

```
Jan  3 2022
220103
```

Disassembly (gcc x86_64):

```
version:
        .string "220103"
```

Comment: ".... YYMMDD with ASCII digits" --> works even if non-ASCII. (Some ancient big iron). 

Answer (score 4):

I wanted the date of compilation in ISO format in a C++ program, so I came up with this:

```
constexpr unsigned int compileYear = (__DATE__[7] - '0') * 1000 + (__DATE__[8] - '0') * 100 + (__DATE__[9] - '0') * 10 + (__DATE__[10] - '0');
constexpr unsigned int compileMonth = (__DATE__[0] == 'J') ? ((__DATE__[1] == 'a') ? 1 : ((__DATE__[2] == 'n') ? 6 : 7))    // Jan, Jun or Jul
                                    : (__DATE__[0] == 'F') ? 2                                                              // Feb
                                    : (__DATE__[0] == 'M') ? ((__DATE__[2] == 'r') ? 3 : 5)                                 // Mar or May
                                    : (__DATE__[0] == 'A') ? ((__DATE__[2] == 'p') ? 4 : 8)                                 // Apr or Aug
                                    : (__DATE__[0] == 'S') ? 9                                                              // Sep
                                    : (__DATE__[0] == 'O') ? 10                                                             // Oct
                                    : (__DATE__[0] == 'N') ? 11                                                             // Nov
                                    : (__DATE__[0] == 'D') ? 12                                                             // Dec
                                    : 0;
constexpr unsigned int compileDay = (__DATE__[4] == ' ') ? (__DATE__[5] - '0') : (__DATE__[4] - '0') * 10 + (__DATE__[5] - '0');

constexpr char IsoDate[] =
{   compileYear/1000 + '0', (compileYear % 1000)/100 + '0', (compileYear % 100)/10 + '0', compileYear % 10 + '0',
    '-',  compileMonth/10 + '0', compileMonth%10 + '0',
    '-',  compileDay/10 + '0', compileDay%10 + '0',
    0
};

// Test that it gets it right today
#include <cstring>
static_assert(strcmp(IsoDate, "2020-11-06") == 0);
```

Comment: It's good. however there is a small bug:

    : (__DATE__[0] == 'M') ? ((__DATE__[1] == 'r') ? 3 : 5)                                 // Mar or May
    : (__DATE__[0] == 'A') ? ((__DATE__[1] == 'p') ? 4 : 8)                                 // Apr or Aug

Comment: Your bugfix is wrong as well. The only change required is `__DATE__[1] == 'p'` in the A`p`ril and August check

Answer (score 3):

Here's a true hack:

```
union {
    const char DOUBLE_DATE[18];
    const char PAD[19];
} DATE_HELPER = { __DATE__ " " __DATE__ };

const char *MY_DATE = DATE_HELPER.DOUBLE_DATE + 7;
```

Comment: +1 for making me compile to test... and working. But too bordering on UB for me to trust every compiler with it :)

Comment: This one lacks the proper termination after the second "dd".

Comment: @JensGustedt: How do you mean?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Did I mention it was a hack? ;-)

Comment: @jxh the string you are producing is `"Mmm dd yyyy Mmm dd yyyy"`, with entry at `7` this gives `"yyyy Mmm dd yyyy"` which is not exactly the string the OP wants.

Comment: @JensGustedt `DOUBLE_DATE` will be truncated to 18 characters (`Mmm dd yyyy Mmm dd`), and the 19th (`\0`) will be added by `PAD`. As long as the compiler truncates the initialization (unsure if that's guaranteed) and the union is static, it would seem to work.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, no, I don't think that union initialization works like that. The byte in in `PAD[18]` is unspecific.

Comment: @JensGustedt: You are right, which is why it is a hack. On most systems (UNIX in particular), the entirety of the bss is zero initialized except for the those memory locations that have other initial values. And I am counting on a truncated initialization.

Comment: @JensGustedt Had to look it up :) The standard isn't extremely clear, but C11 3.6.2 says `No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity
being initialized.`, which afaict would make the initializer invalid (UB?) even if the zero initialization were guaranteed. In the specific case of gcc though, it generates a warning, truncates, and gives the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted the date of compilation in ISO format in a C++ program, so I
> came up with this:

Thanks 'dc42' for your workaround solution. I would like to suggest an alternative solution to compile the month according to the **DATE** format, which may be more clear to all.

```
unsigned int compileMonth = (int)__DATE__[0]+(int)__DATE__[1]+(int)__DATE__[2];
compileMonth = compileMonth == 281 ? 1
             : compileMonth == 269 ? 2
             : compileMonth == 288 ? 3
             : compileMonth == 291 ? 4
             : compileMonth == 295 ? 5
             : compileMonth == 301 ? 6
             : compileMonth == 299 ? 7
             : compileMonth == 285 ? 8
             : compileMonth == 296 ? 9
             : compileMonth == 294 ? 10
             : compileMonth == 307 ? 11
             : compileMonth == 268 ? 12
             : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created 'wrappers' for `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` using C++20 `consteval`, `std::chrono::year_month_day`, `std::chrono:hh_mm_ss`, and accounting for "??" as in [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html):

```
#include <chrono>

consteval std::chrono::year_month_day build_date() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  constexpr auto m2i = [](const char* s) { return (s[0] << 16) | (s[1] << 8) | s[2]; };
  constexpr auto d   = [](int i) { return __DATE__[i] - '0'; };
  month          m;
  switch (m2i(__DATE__)) {
    case m2i("Jan"): m = January; break;
    case m2i("Feb"): m = February; break;
    case m2i("Mar"): m = March; break;
    case m2i("Apr"): m = April; break;
    case m2i("May"): m = May; break;
    case m2i("Jun"): m = June; break;
    case m2i("Jul"): m = July; break;
    case m2i("Aug"): m = August; break;
    case m2i("Sep"): m = September; break;
    case m2i("Oct"): m = October; break;
    case m2i("Nov"): m = November; break;
    case m2i("Dec"): m = December; break;
    default: return {};
  }
  return year(d(10) + 10 * d(9) + 100 * d(8) + 1000 * d(7)) / m / (d(5) + ((__DATE__[4] != ' ') ? 10 * d(4) : 0));
}

consteval std::chrono::hh_mm_ss<std::chrono::seconds> build_time() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  if (__TIME__[0] == '?')
    return {};
  constexpr auto dd = [](int i) { return 10 * (__TIME__[i] - '0') + (__TIME__[i + 1] - '0'); };
  return hh_mm_ss(hours(dd(0)) + minutes(dd(3)) + seconds(dd(6)));
}
```