# Extract only year from date macro

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, macros, c-preprocessor

My question is similar to [Different format of __DATE__ macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739390/different-format-of-date-macro)
but the solutions mentioned there are showing error in my VS 2013 compiler.

I want to just take the year part from **date** macro, so as to make a macro which contains a string like

```
#define BUILD_YEAR_CH0 (__DATE__[ 7])
#define BUILD_YEAR_CH1 (__DATE__[ 8])
#define BUILD_YEAR_CH2 (__DATE__[ 9])
#define BUILD_YEAR_CH3 (__DATE__[ 10])

#define COPY "Copyright"

#define COMPANY "ABCD Lmtd"

#define CYC BUILD_YEAR_CH0 BUILD_YEAR_CH1 BUILD_YEAR_CH2 COMPANY
```

So that I can use the CYC macro to print the concatenated string wherever required.

But once I usethe BUILD_YEAR_CH0 macro/token in CYC macro, it shows error.

I have also tried making a const char buffer which has the exact year value like

```
const char MYEAR[] = { __DATE__[7], __DATE__[8],__DATE__[9],__DATE__[10],'\0' };
```

But again, I was unable to use it inside the CYC macro.
Is it really impossible to accomplish this only with macros, not using any variables ?

Comment: Would a `constexpr` or template function be okay?

Comment: Why bother with the pain that is macros? Why not write a proper function?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sometimes you want to embed the date compilation have taken place in the binary.

Comment: A `char` doesn't make a string.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Sure, but you can usually encapsulate most of that in a function with limited macro abuse. Or you could just rely on the fact that some executable formats include a timestamp, so you can get the info that way.

Comment: Pass the code you show to the pre-processor and inspect its result.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Considering that the OP's using MSVC, they may want to use `CYC` with Resource Compiler.  From what the documentation says, it kinda needs to work with the preprocessor.

Comment: @Dan: The copyright date should be set to the release date, which in the absence of time machines has to be after the date of compilation. The legal problem would be that you'd compile in December 2017, release in January 2018, and as a result your copyright claim expires in 2087 instead of 2088. (Assuming Disney doesn't get copyright extended  to infinity years)

Comment: @Dan: And my point is that it won't matter now, next year, or in 2087. The earliest possible year in which it might matter is 2088. This is because you're making a weaker claim than strictly possible. It _would_ be a significant legal problem if you post-date a copyright date.

Answer (score 1):

The `__DATE__` macro expands to an 11 byte string literal with the format `"Mmm dd yyyy"`. You can initialize a string pointer to point to the 8th byte of this literal, it can later be used as a 4 byte C string with the year part of the compilation date.  This pointer can be local or global, with automatic or static storage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *build_year = __DATE__ + 7;

    printf("This program was compiled in %s\n", build_year);
    return 0;
}
```

You could even use this approach in a macro:

```
#define BUILD_YEAR  (__DATE__ + 7)
```

---

Notes:

- `clang` issues a warning when compiling the above code with `-Weverything`:

  ```
  ctyear.c:4:37: warning: expansion of date or time macro is not reproducible [-Wdate-time]
  ```

  You can disable this warning with `-Wno-date-time`.
- Unfortunately this approach cannot be used for the other parts of the `__DATE__` macro.

---

**EDIT:**  You can also define the macro in the Makefile. With this approach, you have complete control over which fields to include in the expansion:

```
ctyear: ctyear.c
    clang '-DBUILD_YEAR="$(shell date +%Y)"' $< -o $@
```

**ctyear.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COMPANY  "Newco"
#define CYC BUILD_YEAR " " COMPANY

int main(void) {
    printf("Copyright %s\n", CYC);
    return 0;
}
```

If you have a large project with many source files, you probably have a Makefile and you can add `'-DBUILD_YEAR="$(shell date +%Y)"'` to the definition of `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Hi chqrlie, if things where as straightforward, I'd have directly done something like this without posting here . But  here, I have many constrains, this macro is defined in a header file & is being used in several places inside the project . I need to modify the existing hardcoded part & replace it so that all the dependent places shall be affected with the year info , after each compilaition

Comment: @user7083883: does the macro `#define MYEAR  (__DATE__ + 7)` fit your constraints?

Comment: And one more thing is that , I am very much afraid to use a  pointer like this globally instead of a macro. const char *myear = __DATE__ + 7;

Comment: `MYEAR/myear`  is (to me) a really confusing name. Did you mean `MYYEAR/myear`? Now it really reads like "my ear" which is cool but not what it's about. Or is this some naming scheme that is obvious to everyone but me?

Comment: @user7083883: The macro does not have this problem. There is a tiny chance that it may expand to a different value in different modules if the object files (or the library) were compiled in different years.

Comment: @unwind: I agree. I changed the names to `BUILD_YEAR` and `build_year`.

Comment: #define BUILD_YEAR (__DATE__ + 7), is ok, but again I have the same issue. I cannot use it like : #define CYC BUILD_YEAR COMPANY, thanks unwind :)

Comment: @user7083883: there are some limitations as to how you can use this macro. To overcome these, you may need to generate a header file in the Makefile or the configure script.

Comment: Why do you insist on doing `#define CYC BUILD_YEAR COMPANY` if not for having `CYC` being expanded to a string literal *after* pre-processing?

Answer (score 0):

What about using this code:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(s) # s
#define EXPAND(s) STRINGIFY(s)

#define COMPANY "ABCD Lmtd"
#define CYC EXPAND(MYEAR) " "  COMPANY

int main(void)
{
  printf("%s\n", CYC);
}
```

compiling it like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -g main.c -o main -DMYEAR=$(date +"%Y")
```

It prints

```
2017 ABCD Lmtd
```

---

Although I do not understand why you care how the date comes in if its finally available as macro, here's another approach using the `__DATE__` macro:

```
#define CYC strcat((char[4 + 1 + 1 + sizeof COMPANY]){__DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], __DATE__[9], __DATE__[10], ' ', '\0'}, COMPANY)
```

or more flexible

```
#define CYC(s) strcat((char[4 + 1 + 1 + sizeof (s)]){__DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], __DATE__[9], __DATE__[10], ' ', '\0'}, s)
```

Comment: Sorry, as I told, this is not related to printing the date of my project. This is a huge project which has a GUI output that has this CYC macro value being displayed in several places of the GUI menu . Anyway thanks for input

Comment: Hi alk, what I am trying to mention is,  I can't just use a makefile here (since VS 2013 proj) . 2nd thing is, I wrongly mentioned in OP that I want to print date, its not correct. Current proj uses this macro for for various purposes like embedding this copyright info on various GUI items e.t.c). Since this is GUI project, there is no print output here. Also I didn't quite understand this :#define CYC(s) strcat((char[4 + 1 + 1 + sizeof (s)]){__DATE__[7], __DATE__[8], __DATE__[9], __DATE__[10], ' ', '\0'}, s). How this works and how can I use it ?, can you please throw some light on this ?

Comment: @user7083883: As you mention GUI: Is your requirement for having a string literal available (as opposed to a something evaluating to a `char*`-pointer) because, the `#define` is referred by a windows resource file, an `.rc`?

Comment: exactly, its used by .rc

Comment: #define MYEAR  (__DATE__ + 7)
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define COPY "Copyright"
#define COMPANY "ABCD Lmtd"
#define YEAR COPY xstr(MYEAR) COMPANY

o/p - > Copyright("Jan 30 2017" + 7)ABCD Lmtd

Comment: @user7083883: The code you show in this previous command solves you issue, right?

Comment: Nopes. it just prints the whole date along with the RHS  "+ 7", (not just the year)

Comment: @user7083883: Ah yes, I see. The resource compiler just invokes the C pre-processor, not the C-compiler, so you can not rely on any C-operations. The pre-processor is not capable of doing string parsing. So your approach simply doesn't work. :-( Still, changing the code by hand once a year shouldn't be a problem, right? ;-)

Comment: How do you build you project's components though?

Comment: that was a very good piece of info for me (pre-rocessor related), thanks :). Initially, I tried to modify the main project itself which I found was quite tiresome, since errors where thrown at all occurrences of that macro. No I am doing my testing after creating an empty C++ project in VS 2013 and just building it.