# Compile date and time using cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I want to use cmake to set VERSION to a release version in case of release builds and to the compile time otherwise.

When using make for development builds, obtaining the compile time was easy via

```
-DVERSION=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M`
```

which could be used straight forward by c/c++ source code. Unfortunately, I haven't found out how the same can be achieved when using cmake.

```
string(TIMESTAMP VERSION "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
add_definitions(-DVERSION="${VERSION}")
```

sets VERSION to the time cmake was executed. How can I set VERSION to the compile time when using cmake (to avoid having to fiddle with `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` in the absence of a RELEASE flag)?

Comment: [Here's a useful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419255/how-to-get-cmake-to-create-timestamp-file-after-an-actual-build-link-do-nothin) for your problem. You'll need to ensure that you have some command like `date` available with your host build environment. A generic solution using the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros would also be easy by just providing a header file containing the necessary definitions, that is generated (or at least touched) on each build (as a pre-build action)

Comment: Generally speaking, a version number's purpose is to be able to *reproduce the exact source files a binary was built with*. As such, using the timestamp of the *compilation* is a very, **very** poor choice. Assign and maintain proper version numbers, or if you cannot be bothered to do that, use something from your version control software (branch / revision for SVN, hashcode for GIT). Just don't use a compilation timestamp, it's even worse than having no version at all, because you could have a newer compilation of older sources, which would be confusing for everyone including youself.

Comment: @DevSolar i think you mix different ideas here. It's the purpose of revision, not version, to be able to reproduce the exact source files. The purpose of build ID is to be able to find the exact build artifacts on our build/dev machine. The purpose of app/lib version is actually broad, starting from marketing purposes and ending in backward compatibility issues. The app/lib version may or may not contain build ID or revision. It's up to dev (ops) how to track specific version to build or revision. As to timestamp, it may very well serve as build ID for dev builds.

Comment: @AlexChe: The problem with a timestamp build ID is that a timestamp does not allow to trace the binary back to its sources unless you are working with a single code branch only -- and even then you will have to fiddle with the VCS you are using. A VCS revision is better, but still loses its informational value when you e.g. have to (or want to) migrate your VCS. IMHO you should have a product version, component versions, and ideally use some VCS-specific way to tag the sources that went into a component build that you could migrate to a different VCS should the need arise.

Answer (score 38):

For relatively recent versions of CMake (>=2.8.11):

```
string(TIMESTAMP {output variable} [{format string}] [UTC])
```

(see http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/string.html). For example:

```
string(TIMESTAMP TODAY "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: Could you please add several examples?

Comment: `string(TIMESTAMP ...` is cached until you edit `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 8):

My cross-platform solution on the first run of CMake creates a file `timestamp.cmake` in the binary directory and defines a target `timestamp` which runs the generated file. The file `timestamp.cmake` forms an ISO 8601 time stamp string using the `STRING` CMake command and writes it to a file `timestamp.h` with a `#define _TIMEZ_` preprocessor directive prepended (defines with one leading underscore are okay; defines with two leading underscores should not be user-defined).

Include the following in your main CMake file.

```
# build time in UTC ISO 8601
FILE (WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/timestamp.cmake "STRING(TIMESTAMP TIMEZ UTC)\n")
FILE (APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/timestamp.cmake "FILE(WRITE timestamp.h \"#ifndef TIMESTAMP_H\\n\")\n")
FILE (APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/timestamp.cmake "FILE(APPEND timestamp.h \"#define TIMESTAMP_H\\n\\n\")\n")
FILE (APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/timestamp.cmake "FILE(APPEND timestamp.h \"#define _TIMEZ_ \\\"\${TIMEZ}\\\"\\n\\n\")\n")
FILE (APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/timestamp.cmake "FILE(APPEND timestamp.h \"#endif // TIMESTAMP_H\\n\")\n")
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET (
    timestamp
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/timestamp.cmake
    ADD_DEPENDENCIES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/timestamp.cmake)
```

Then use the `ADD_DEPENDENCIES` CMake command to make your main target (probably the main executable file) dependent on the `timestamp` target. It is always considered out-of-date by CMake, so it is being refreshed every time the main target rebuilds, refreshing the build time, as requested.

```
ADD_DEPENDENCIES (${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${BINARY_NAME} timestamp)
```

You can specify multiple additional dependencies separated by a white space with this command, if you need to.

Then you can just `#include "timestamp.h"` (assuming that the CMake binary dir is in the include path, which usually is. If not, that's simple: `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})`), and use `_TIMEZ_` whenever you want to have the build time stamp in ISO 8601 format (or, in fact, whatever you like: you can specify it yourself, [see CMake documentation for `STRING` command usage](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/string.html)).

This could've been made simpler by directly (by hand) creating the file `timestamp.cmake` and adding it to your code repository, but I've considered it as not being clean enough. It is a general drawback of CMake you cannot access the time stamp string forming procedure (the one used in the `STRING` CMake command) at the stage where CMake's backend, whatever it is (for example, GNU make) runs so one has to use a separate CMake file and call it at that stage. This could've been done much much simpler and cleaner if you could call the CMake time stamp string forming procedure in the "CMake command mode" (`cmake -E` type of invocation), for example, like this: `cmake -E date [format] [UTC]`, but alas. I've [filed a ticket in the CMake's Mantis bug tracker](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15649).

You can help that to happen by supporting my feature request posting some comments showing how much you need this on it.

Comment: Defines with a leading underscore *and then* a capital letter are actually not ok. (Not that this is too important.)

Comment: (this is old, but) it is my understanding that _all_ (unscoped) symbols beginning with a leading underscore are reserved to the implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you could use the compiler macros `__DATE__` `__TIME__` inside your code instead getting it from cmake. Worth mentioning that you will need to do clean/make to update these values (since GCC embeds it, if the object is already compiled it wont compile again, so no date/time change)

Comment: This is reasonable advice but it has the downside of preventing totally reproducible builds since the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` will change based on compilation time. Instead it may be better to pass these values in as different macros at compilation time.

Comment: Few years after, I really agree with you. With __DATE__ and __TIME__ one will not be able to create a 1:1 binary from a specific release.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with the following solution:

```
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    add_custom_target(
        "linktimestamp"
        ALL
        COMMAND date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' > "linktimestamp.txt"
        COMMAND objcopy --input binary --output elf64-x86-64 --binary-architecture i386:x86-64 --rename-section .data=.rodata,CONTENTS,ALLOC,LOAD,READONLY,DATA "linktimestamp.txt" "linktimestamp.o"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        COMMENT "link timestamp: ${LINK_TIMESTAMP}"
        )
else()
    add_custom_target(
        "linktimestamp"
        ALL
        COMMAND date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' > "linktimestamp.txt"
        COMMAND objcopy --input binary --output elf32-i386 --binary-architecture i386 --rename-section .data=.rodata,CONTENTS,ALLOC,LOAD,READONLY,DATA "linktimestamp.txt" "linktimestamp.o"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        COMMENT "link timestamp: ${LINK_TIMESTAMP}"
        )
endif()
#add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} "linktimestamp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/linktimestamp.o")
```

Binary target `${PROJECT_NAME}` linked every time with updated section.

*Qt* code to get this timestamp:

```
extern char _binary_linktimestamp_txt_start[];
//extern char _binary_linktimestamp_txt_end[];
extern char _binary_linktimestamp_txt_size[];
const auto text = QByteArray::fromRawData(_binary_linktimestamp_txt_start, reinterpret_cast< std::intptr_t >(_binary_linktimestamp_txt_size));
qDebug() << QDateTime::fromString(QString::fromUtf8(text), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same problem a while back, and ended up writing [this repo](https://github.com/kraiskil/cmake_timestamp) as a solution. Just add it as a CMake subdirectory, and `build_date_str` will contain the *link time* of your program.

In the case github goes offline before stackoverflow, the idea of this solution is:

1. Create a `BUILD_TIME` CMake variable with `string(TIMESTAMP ...` as in the above solutions.
2. Compile a small library that records the `BUILD_TIME` into a global variable (that you can print or whatever) from your program.
3. Make the building of that library depend on a custom target that removes the variable from the CMake cache with `cmake -U BUILD_TIME`.

This means that every time you build your project, the dependencies are checked, and the CMake cache is cleared, causing CMake to be re-run for this timestamp library.
A downside of this solution is that if you have a CI system, any parameters you pass to your CMake step you need to remember to pass to your build step too.