# How to capture last modified date of a file in avariable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How to capture last modified date of a file in a variable.

Consider a directory '/home/abc/Desktop/swa` containing files:

```
abc1.txt
abc2.txt
abc3.txt
```

How to capture the last modified date for file `abc2.txt` in a variable?

Comment: Use command substitution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print a file's last modified date in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391208/print-a-files-last-modified-date-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 3):

Use `stat` like this:

```
mtime=$(stat -c "%y" abc2.txt)
echo $mtime
2014-03-04 09:15:31.000000000 +0000
```

Or, if you just want age in seconds since the Epoch for simple comparisons:

```
mtime=$(stat -c "%Y" abc2.txt)
echo $mtime
1393924531
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) e.g.

```
modate=$(stat --format='%Y' abc1.txt)
```