# Copy files (images) to folder structured according to creation date

Tags: bash, macos, file, date

I use a bash script on OSX, which copies all iamges from an SD-card to my external HDD.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
now=$(date +"%d%m%Y") 
mkdir -p /Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/$now 
find /Volumes/Untitled/DCIM/ -name '*.JPG' -print0 | xargs -0 -J % rsync --progress --times % /Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/$now
```

This script creates a folder according to the present date and copies all the images to this destination.

I would like to modify this script a little bit, so that each image is copied to a folder which is named with the creation date (same like last modified) of the certain image.

So if i have 3 files like:

- image1.jpg - lastModified: 08102016
- image2.jpg - lastModified: 10102016
- image3.jpg - lastModified: 08102016

i would like to get 2 folders at the destination (/Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/) with

- Folder 08102016 - contains image1 and image3
- Folder 10102016 - contains image2

I found the "stat" command ([Print a file's last modified date in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391208/print-a-files-last-modified-date-in-bash-script)) that could be used here to get out the modified-date, but I'm not really sure how to correctly inetgrate this.

My idea would be to have a loop like (pseudocode)

```
#!/bin/bash 
for i in /Volumes/Untitled/DCIM/*/*.jpg; do
  creationdate = stat -f "%Sm" -t "%d%m%Y" "$i"
  rsync --progress --times $i /Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/$creationdate
done
```

how can i use a for loop for the path /Volumes/Untitled/DCIM/*/*.jpg?

Or does anybody of you know another direction for a proper solution?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is my working code (with a counter):

```
#!/bin/bash 
counter=0
completefilenumber=$( find "/Volumes/Untitled/DCIM/" -type f -iname '*.JPG' | wc -l )
find "/Volumes/Untitled/DCIM/" -type f -iname "*.JPG" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' img; do
  counter=$((counter+1))
  echo "$img (Nr. ${counter}/${completefilenumber})" 
  creationdate=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t '%d%m%Y' $img)
  mkdir -p /Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/$creationdate
  rsync --times $img /Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/$creationdate
done
echo "Script done!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your `stat` code works.  You're "pseudocode" is very close to correct.

All you need to do is capture the output of the stat command so that you can assign it to your creationdate

```
#!/bin/bash 
for img in /Volumes/Untitled/DCIM/*/*.jpg; do
  creationdate=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%d%m%Y" "${img}")
  rsync --progress --times $img "/Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/${creationdate}"
done
```

Look into "command substitution".

Basically you can wrap any command in $() to capture it's output.  This allows you to then assign it to a variable.  It gets more complicated than that and there are some gotchas but that's the general concept and some google searching will take you to many articles that can explain it better than i can.

Also using `$i` when it isn't an index confused me so I changed that.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you're using stat, `ls` is a good way to get time. Since you want to go file by file, rsync probably is a bit to heavy duty. One solution:

```
for file in /Volumes/Untitled/DCIM/*/*.jpg; do
    creationdate=$(ls -lt --time-style="+%m%d%y" "$file" | cut -d" " -f6)
    mkdir -p /Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/$creationdate
    cp $file /Volumes/WDigital/Images/Project1/$creationdate
done
```