# BASH: determine the age of the most recent file in directory

Tags: bash

I need to copy the most recent file from certain directory, and alert if it is older than 7 days.
For instance:
In /home/user directory there are 3 files: 1.05.2017, 2.05.2017, 3.05.2017.
I use ls -Art /home/user to pick up the 3.05.2017 as the most recent file.
How do i alert (echo) that it older than 1 week? 'find' command doesn't help much here.

Comment: This post may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391208/print-a-files-last-modified-date-in-bash

Comment: I'm astonished at how bad most of the duplicate questions' answers are on this site. Review [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- there are *much* better tools than `ls` available.

Comment: `{ read -r -d ' ' mtime && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; } < <(find /home/user -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%T@ %P\0' | sort -rnz)` will put the timestamp on the file, in UNIX time (seconds since epoch) in the variable `mtime`, and the name of it in `filename`. And unlike `ls`-based approaches, it does so in a way that's completely robust against bizarre filenames that would make output from `ls` something other than the literal name itself.

Comment: At that point, you just take the current epoch time, and check whether the difference between the two numbers is more than `$(( 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 ))` (the number of seconds in a week).

Comment: Assuming the filename of the most recent file is save in $RFILE, I would create a file that is a week old using the command `touch -t $(date -d '1 week ago' +%Y%m%d%H%M) oldfile` (assuming there is no file already named oldfile, perhaps see `man mktemp`). Then check with a test `if [[ "$RFILE" -ot "oldfile" ]]; then ALERT_HERE; fi`.

Comment: Don't think this question is duplicate, as it is not about theoretical opportunities to detect the age of the files (which have been widely discussed allover the internet). This more in vein of pinging for bright engineering approach to find the simplest and easiest way to compare the most recent file to current date for light backup. The approach should be dynamic, the one suggested by @Deathgrip looks pretty attractive, will try that, thanks!