# How to collect filename, last modified date and last modified date +30 days and add to HTML table?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script which will take the contents of a directory and print the filename (minus the extension), last modified date and the last modified date + 30 days into a HTML table. For example:

| Filename | Last Modified Date | Last Modified Date + 30 days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | Fri 18 Nov 12:35:00 PM EST | Sun 18 Dec 12:35:00 PM EST |

So far I have managed to write a script that will create the HTML table and add the filename without the extension however I am struggling with adding data for the other two columns. Here is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash



head='<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <div class="u-expanded-width u-table u-table-responsive u-table-1">
          <table class="u-table-entity u-table-entity-1">
            <colgroup>
              <col width="33.3%">
              <col width="33.3%">
              <col width="33.3%">
            </colgroup>
            <thead class="u-align-center u-custom-font u-grey-5 u-heading-font u-table-header u-table-header-1">
              <tr style="height: 40px;">
                <th class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-table-cell">Community String</th>
                <th class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-table-cell">Simulation Created</th>
                <th class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-dark-1 u-table-cell">Simulation Expires</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="u-align-center u-table-body">
            <tr style="height: 7px;">
            </tr>'

tail='</tbody>
</table>
</html>'

printf '%s\n' "$head"

shopt -s nullglob

uploaddate="$(find /usr/local/data/ . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.snmprec" -printf "<tr><td>%Tc</td></tr>\n")"

expirydate="$(find /usr/local/data/ -mtime +30 -type f -name "*.snmprec")"

for file in /usr/local/snmpsim/data/ephemeral/*.snmprec; do
  [[ $file =~ ([^/]+).snmprec$ ]] &&
  Filename=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  SimulationCreated=$uploaddate
  SimulationExpires=$expirydate
  printf ' <tr>\n    <td>%s</td>\n    <td>%s</td>\n    <td>%s</td>\n </tr>\n' "$Filename" "$SimulationCreated" "$SimulationExpires"
done
```

My command below collects the last modified date however it prints all the dates into each row in the table in the Filename column like below:

```
uploaddate="$(find /usr/local/data/ . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.snmprec" -printf "<tr><td>%Tc</td></tr>\n")"
```

| Filename | Last Modified Date | Last Modified Date + 30 days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test |  |  |
| Fri 18 Nov 12:35:00 PM EST |  |  |

How would I be able to get the details I need and format them in the table like the first one above?

Comment: Print the date of last modification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391208/print-a-files-last-modified-date-in-bash/16391221.  Date arithmetic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467/date-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-scripts.  And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: According to your code, `$uploaddate` is a **string** containing the modification date of all the `/usr/local/data/*.snmprec` files, `$expirydate` is a **string** containing the paths of the `/usr/local/data/**/*.snmprec` files that have been modified more than 30 days ago, and `$file` is for looping though the `/usr/local/snmpsim/data/ephemeral/*.snmprec` files. Do you think it makes sense?